# How to uninstall app on tvOS Simulator

Tags: simulator, tvos

I tried long press on my app icon but it showing me no close button like iOS simulator. I have too many test apps on my screen don't know how to uninstall that. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its pretty easy. Just follow given steps:

> Settings -> General -> Manage Storage

And from here you can easily uninstall your app.